# Full Stack Developer Practice: Where should I start?

Tags: career-development, careers

I am currently a junior in high school, and I’m looking into developer careers for my long term future. Initially, I looked into software development, but then I started wanting to do full stack development, as it pays more and offers more versatility. I’m not sure if this is the right place to ask, but if I wanted to get practice in with projects for example, where should I start?

Currently, I know C++, a little bit of C#, and am getting deeper into Java and Python. I’m aware that full stack is going to need more than just programming languages, so I imagine I can practice web and database development later, as it will be one of my classes next year anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your long term future should be detemined by a solid education. Whether that is an apprenticeship, vocational school, trade school or college/university is probably dependent on your countries education system.

For now, you are in school, do what is *fun*. Whatever interests you. If that is programming, great. Do it. Do what you *like* about it.

When it comes to a job, get a solid education. It does not have to be top notch. Nobody needs an Ivy league software developer. Any education can get you going. But it should not be you and a youtube tutorial. It should be an institution with a history and good track record of training software developers.